# Hibernate/JPA version concurrency control and DTO/change command patterns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-concurrency

I would like to use `@Version` for optimistic concurrency control with JPA & Hibernate.

I know how it works in the typical scenario of two parallel transactions. I also know that if I have a CRUD with 1:1 mapping between the form and entity, I can just pass `version` along as a hidden field and use this to prevent concurrent modifications by users.

What about more interesting cases, which use DTOs or change command patterns? Is it possible to use `@Version` in this scenario as well, and how?

Let me give you an example.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    @Version private int version;
    private String someField;
    private String someOtherField;
    // ...
}
```

Now let's say two users open the GUI for this, make some modifications and save changes (not at the same time, so the transactions don't overlap).

If I pass the entire entity around, the second transaction will fail:

```
@Transactional
public void updateMyEntity(MyEntity newState) {
    entityManager.merge(newState);
}
```

That's good, but I don't like the idea of passing entities everywhere and sometimes would use DTOs, change commands etc.

For simplicity change command is a map, eventually used in a call like this on some service:

```
@Transactional
public void updateMyEntity(int entityId, int version, Map<String, Object> changes) {
    MyEntity instance = loadEntity(entityId);
    for(String field : changes.keySey()) {
        setWithReflection(instance, field, changes.get(field));
    }
    // version is unused - can I use it somehow?
}
```

Obviously, if two users open my GUI, both make a change, and execute it one after another, in this case both changes will be applied, and the last one will "win". I would like this scenario to detect concurrent modification as well (the second user should get an exception).

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is a setter for your `private int version` field and when you update the entity, you set it in your entity. Of course your DTO must always transport version data. Eventually, you would do also something like:

```
MyEntity instance = loadEntity(entityId);
entityManager.detach(instance);
for(String field : changes.keySey()) {
    setWithReflection(instance, field, changes.get(field));
}
//set also the version field, if the loop above does not set it
entityManager.merge(instance);
```